# Coudn't get value from textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

I have a textbox called `txtUprice` which gets the value from a data-grid view, but when I tried get value of the `txtUprice`-textbox in a message box (with or without changing the text box value) I'm getting an error:

> Input string was not in a correct format

I have tried changing the data type in sql  where i get the value to the datagrid.

To get the value for textbox from datagrid i have used this:

```
txtUprice.Text = datagridview.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString()
```

To take the textbox value to message-box i have used this:

```
int unitprice;
unitprice = int.Parse(txtUprice.Text);
MessageBox.Show(unitprice.ToString());
```

Comment: The error is telling you that whatever the text is, it is not an integer value.  Note that DGV columns are (or can be) typed such that `myDGV.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value` is *already* an integer...just cast it.

Comment: Have you verified what's inside the TextBox at this time? `int.Parse` only parses integers (not a conversion tool). Maybe you have a value that exceeds `int.MaxValue` or not an integer type. Also try to `Trim()` it.

Comment: @jimi, trimming shouldn't be necessary, as int.Parse should be able to handle leading and trailing whitespaces...

Comment: @elgonzo  `Trim()` doesn't just trim white spaces.

Comment: @jimi, let me ask differently: what character(s) would int.Parse(string) have a problem with that Trim() removes?

Comment: Addtionally to what others said, another failure mode is when your TextBox contains a whole number in scientifc E notation (exponent notation) or a number using thousands separator/grouping delimiter. `int.Parse(string)` does not handle thousands separator/grouping delimiter nor E notation, even if the string in question contains an E notation number that is both whole and falls within the value range of the 32-bit `int` type. However, for those particular situations, `int.Parse` has an overload allowing parsing of such number representations: `int.Parse(string, NumberStyles)`

Comment: Why not end our misery and *tell us* what the string is that you are trying to parse.  In other words a [MCVe].  If the *"string is not a number"* as below, then it will never be able to be stored in an int variable

Comment: @elgonzo `string s = "string s = "£ 123 ";`. `int.Parse(s.Trim('£'));` It would fail even specifying `NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol` if `£` is not the current currency symbol. Just an example, I don't know what that string contains. If it's something trimmable...

Comment: @Jimi, ah alright. I thought you were speaking about the parameterless Trim() overload.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error beacuse of this line

```
unitprice = int.Parse(txtUprice.Text);
```

Reason is, you are trying to parse some string to integer which cannot. like 10%.

Instead of that use like this.

```
  //int unitprice;
  //unitprice = int.Parse(txtUprice.Text);
  MessageBox.Show(txtUprice.Text);
```

Or still you want to convert that to int, use try parse

```
    int num1;
    bool res = int.TryParse(txtUprice.Text, out num1);
    if (res == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("String is not a number");
    }
    else{
        MessageBox.Show(num1.ToString()); 
    }
```

Comment: i have try parse method but i got "string is not a number"

Comment: is there any other methods to convert that into a int

Comment: i have only numeric value in that textbox

Comment: use float type then

Comment: can you please give sample number you trying to convert?